# r - select first values after lead/lag (dplyr)

Tags: r, lag, transition, survival-analysis, lead

I am trying to simply select the first two or three values of a `leaded` variable.

Imagine my data looks like this

```
       id variable  leadvar
1       a        0     0
2       a        1     0
3       a        1     0
4       b        0     0
5       b        0     0
6       b        1     0
7       c        0     0
8       c        0     0
9       c        0     0
10      d        1     0
11      d        1     0
12      d        1     0
```

What I want is to first `lead` the `variable`, with the condition that `lead minus 1 = 0` (for each `id`) (which means that the lead variable should take `1` if a `1` is preceded by `0`), such as :

```
       id variable  leadvar
1       a        0     1
2       a        1     0
3       a        1     0
4       b        0     0
5       b        0     1
6       b        1     0
7       c        0     0
8       c        0     0
9       c        0     0
10      d        1     0
11      d        1     0
12      d        1     0
```

and then select the first rows after the lead (as well as the lead variable itself), like this :

```
       id variable  leadvar
        a        0     1
        a        1     0

        b        0     1
        b        1     0
```

I am struggling with the last step. I would like to be able to select freely the numbers of rows after the lead. How can I do this ?

My code is :

In order to compute the `lead`

```
library(dplyr) 

dt = dt %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(leadvar = ifelse(variable == 0 & lead(variable == 1, default = 0), 1, 0) )
```

What I tried for selecting 2 rows after the lead, but it doesn't work

```
dt %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(V4 = variable + leadvar) %>% mutate(m = 1:n()) %>% filter(m < 3)
```

The data

```
dt = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
variable = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), lead = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "variable", "lead"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I neither understand the logic behind `lead` (What does `lead minus 1 = 0` mean?), neither I see `V2` or `V1` anywhere in the data.

Comment: I also think you want to use `lead(variable, default = 0) == 1` instead of `lead(variable == 1, default = 0)` though in this special case it might not make a difference

Comment: Either way, this seem to work nicely if you convert `dt` to a `data.table` for any `m` (first time I see those packages working better together than separately) `setDT(dt) %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(if(any(lead == 1)) (which.max(lead):(which.max(lead) + 1)))` This will work correctly even if you'll set `+3` while using `data.table` syntax it will return `NA`s too `setDT(dt)[, if(any(lead == 1)) .SD[(which.max(lead):(which.max(lead) + 3))], by = id]`

Comment: @akrun did you do `setDT(dt)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I was just copy/pasting your code. using `dplyr_0.4.3.9001` and `data.table_1.9.7`

Comment: @akrun it works for me nicely

Comment: could you write it as an answer please @DavidArenburg

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions to this problem using *dplyr*, the first involves creating an additional variable (**tailvar**) to catch if both **variable** and **leadvar** are 1. As *dplyr* does not preserve row numbering, I have created an extra column (**rowid**) to demonstrate that the solution selects the requested rows.

```
dt %>% mutate(leadvar = ifelse(variable == 0 & lead(variable) == 1, 1, 0), 
          tailvar = ifelse(lag(leadvar, default = 0) == 1, 1, 0),
          rowid = row_number()) %>% filter(leadvar ==1 | tailvar ==1)
```

which gives:

```
     id variable leadvar tailvar rowid
  (chr)    (int)   (dbl)   (dbl) (int)
1     a        0       1       0     1
2     a        1       0       1     2
3     b        0       1       0     5
4     b        1       0       1     6
5     c        0       1       0     9
6     d        1       0       1    10
5     d        1       0       1    11
```

To select the leading row and another 2 rows after the leader you would need to use *lag(lag(leadvar))* instead. As you would need to nest as many lag calls as needed to get the value you want, it is perhaps not the best solution.

A more elegant solution using *dplyr*, would be to create a new column using *group_by* and *cumsum*. All that is required is to filter if **leadvar** is 1 or the new column (**csvar**) has the **n** value which you desire.

```
dt %>% mutate(leadvar = ifelse(variable == 0 & lead(variable) == 1, 1, 0), 
              rowid = row_number()) %>%  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(csvar=cumsum(variable)) %>% filter(leadvar == 1 | csvar == 2)
```

which gives:

```
     id variable leadvar rowid csvar
  (chr)    (int)   (dbl) (int) (int)
1     a        0       1     1     0
2     a        1       0     3     2
3     b        0       1     5     0
4     c        0       1     9     0
5     d        1       0    11     2
```

This solution only works for rows with variable == 1, if you wanted to get any row after the leader you would have to create a dummy column filled with 1 then *group_by* and *cumsum* on that.